# Getting all cities in a specific country using OpenStreetMap

Tags: json, openstreetmap

I've trying to find a way to use the OpenStreetMap API to get a list of all cities in a specific country with their longitude, latitude for an iOS app to develop.

However I been unable to do so. I've been trying to use the Overpass API but I just can'T find the right parameters to list all cities (and not just the top 1000 or so).

Does anyone know a way to do this that returns proper JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query isn't (IMHO) a good one for an API, as your results are very sparse but need to run over all the data (no general indexing).

So get an [OSM extact](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet), filter it with [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) and then do your own processing on the results.

Keep in mind, that a town can be modelled differently in OSM:

- as tagged node e.g. [place=city](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/City)
- as landuse area (also with additional place tags)
- as [boundary](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundary) so, a (multipolygon)relation

You might also want to have a look at [nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for geocoding and the [legal FAQ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ) for distributing OSM data.

Comment: "Planet.osm is the OpenStreetMap data in one file: all the nodes, ways and relations that make up our map. A new version is released every week. It's a big file (XML variant over 498GB uncompressed, 36.1GB bz2 compressed and 25.2GB PBF)." - I think it's better to just request from openstreetmap nominatim api or similar because not many people can work with a dataset that large

Answer (score 1):

Using Overpass API.

```
area["ISO3166-1"="CY"]->.a1;
(
  nwr[place="city"](area.a1);
);
out body;
```

[Link](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1cvU). Open console and click run to see the request and response.

Or use curl

```
curl 'https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter' \
 --data-raw 'data=[out:json];area["ISO3166-1"="CY"]->.a1;
(
nwr[place="city"](area.a1);
);
out body;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Overpass_API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)

For example, all states of Germany:

```
 http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(rel[admin_level="4"](47,6,55,15););out;
```

Comment: so I managed to run it via `curl 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter' --data-raw 'data=(rel[admin_level="4"](47,6,55,15););out;' ` but it brings tons of data. Can it be more concise? Can it return JSON btw?

Comment: (47,6,55,15) is not a country