# How to get the list of coordinates of all cities in the world using OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am using OpenStreetMap API with C++ and can get data around a point if I give the latitude and longitude. Now I want to give random coordinates, is there a way to get list of coordinates of all cities in the world?

Comment: You should have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501075/getting-all-cities-in-a-specific-country-using-openstreetmap. You can also look at https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/place=city#overview which shows more than 20,000 objects with 'place=city'

Comment: @XaC I do not need to use extracts as mentioned in your linked question's answer as I don't need large amount of data at a time. I just need coordinates of all cities in the world, and then randomly I will select one city and get the data for that. So if I can get all coordinates with tag place="city", it would be enough. But still trying to figure out how to get that.

Comment: this question helped me get list of all cities in country
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312388/extracting-cities-in-belgium-using-overpass-api